# C array of structure (exception thrown)

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, strdup

I have created an array of structure Human which consists of `char *name`.

I use function like this:

```
Human *createHuman(char *name){
    Human *h = malloc(sizeof(Human));
    h->name = strdup(name);
    return h;
}
```

I have tested this function, it works perfectly, but my problem starts when i use it like this:

```
void gen_Humans(Human array[MAX], int n){
    //n == max;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        char *name = gen_name_function_used_before_WORKING();
        array[i] = *createHuman(*name);
    }
    …
}
```

As I said, if I generate one human it works just fine.
I debugged my code and when I got to the point of `strdup(name)` it threw me this:

```
my error: Exception thrown at 0x53DCF6E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in project.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000070.
```

I am using VS 2017 Enterprise.

Comment: This does not include a [mcve] (your `createHuman` function doesn't return anything)

Comment: Yes n==max and createhuman returns h, thanks for comments! :)

Comment: you have a weird way of creating Humans.  1) You are sending an already allocated array of human structures rather than an array of pointers to human structures. 2) you are not using `createHuman` correctly in the loop it should be `createHuman(name)` not `createHuman(*name)` 3) you are then trying to copy a malloc'd human (returned from createHuman) to copy to the array (already allocated) which will create memory leaks because you are not storing the pointers allocated by malloc to free them later

Comment: You're getting what is close to a null pointer exception — you're accessing address 112 (0x70) instead of 0 (0x00), that's about all.  Take a good look at the return value from `gen_name_function_used_before_WORKING()` because it quite possibly isn't working.  Also, you're leaking memory; the `*createHuman()` on the RHS means that you lose the pointer to the structure and the duplicated name.  You need to capture the return value from the `gen_name_function_used_before_WORKING()` function in a pointer, then copy it, and then free both the name component and the structure pointed at.

Comment: Is this question answered?

Comment: @moritzSchmidt yes thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

When calling your function `createHuman` you are passing the value of your name:

```
array[i] = *createHuman(*name);
```

When building this application, Iam getting the following compiler warning (GCC):

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'createHuman' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

since your function `createHuman` expects the adress of the name, you should also pass the address. For example:

```
array[i] = *createHuman(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @MortizSchmidt's answer:

- You are not checking the results of `malloc()`. You should do so, even if the chances of failure are small.
- You are leaking memory - since you never free the `malloc()`ed memory nor do you keep the pointer anywhere. Remember C is not like Java - assignment is not an assignment of a reference.
- Note that the `MAX` indicator in the function signature doesn't have any effect. The parameter is an int* any way you write it: `int* array`, `int array[]` or `int array[MAX]`.

Actually, why even allocate the Human structure rather than just space for the string?

```
struct Human createHuman(char *name){
    if (name == NULL) {
        struct Human h = { NULL };
        return h;
    }
    struct Human h = { strdup(name) };
    if (h.name == NULL) { /* handle error here */ }
    return h;
}

void gen_Humans(Human array[MAX], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *name = gen_name_function_used_before_WORKING();
        array[i] = createHuman(name);
    }
    …
}
```

This has the added benefit of initializing all fields in `Human` after `name` to 0.