# C creating struct-pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am trying to store my struct `Human` into an array while generating one in a `for` loop. I am completely helpless since I am fairly new to pointers and cannot get this one strip of code working. 
My biggest questions are

- how to store such `Human` in an array of `Human`s
- How to access `Human`'s variables and work with them

Here's my current code:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} Date;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    Date Birth_date;
} Human;

char gen_name() {
    char *name[5];

    name[0] = "Zoro";
    name[1] = "Peter";
    name[2] = "Ambrozsy";
    name[3] = "Chuanita";
    name[4] = "Jack";

    int x = rand() % 5;

    return (name[x]);
}

Human *createHuman(char *name, int day, int month, int year) {
    Human *h = malloc(sizeof(Human));

    h->name = name;
    h->Birth_date.day = day;
    h->Birth_date.month = month;
    h->Birth_date.year = year;

    return h;
}

void gen_Humans(Human array[], int n) {
    // n == MAX
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *name = gen_name();
        int day = gen_day();
        int month = gen_month();
        int year = gen_year();

        array[i] = *createHuman(name, day, month, year);
    }
}

int main() {
    Human *human_array[MAX];

    gen_Humans(human_array, MAX);
    printHuman(human_array, MAX);
}
```

Comment: What is the scope of name?

Comment: change `char gen_name()`  by `char *gen_name`

Comment: You have a memory leak, you're never freeing the memory allocated by `malloc(sizeof(Human))`. `array[i]` is a copy of the structure.

Comment: You need to post the `main()` function that uses these functions, so we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: See also a previous post by MirEso: [C - Array of structure (exception thrown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693698/c-array-of-structure-exception-thrown) — asked about 3 hours before this question.

Comment: @Barmar I've added main :)  I've progressed and facing another problem that after running my code just fine, after pressing enter on getchar i gen runtime error saying that stack around the variable human_array is corrupted

Comment: The call `gen_Humans(human_array, MAX);` shouldn't compile (cleanly) because there's a type mismatch between the array argument (array of pointers to humans) and what the function expects (array of humans, or pointer to humans).  You cannot afford to try running code when the compiler is complaining about it — it knows more about C than you do at the moment (and does its utmost to compile what you give it into sane code, and only witters when it thinks you have a bug in your code).

Comment: You should be getting lots of warnings about type mismatches when you compile this code. These should help you understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar and Jonathan I'm very sorry for looking only on build report tab and ignoring ERROR tab, if you would be so patient with me and help me with this warning where it says: 'function': 'Human *' differs in levels of indirection from 'Employee *[30]'

Answer (score 0):

`human_array` is an array of pointers, so you need to declare it the same way in `get_Humans()`:

```
void gen_Humans(Human *array[], int n)
```

Then you shouldn't dereference the pointer that `createHuman()` returns:

```
array[i] = createHuman(name, day, month, year);
```

You haven't shown `printHuman()`, but it also needs to be similar. Within it, you would print individual humans with something like:

```
printf("%s %d-%02d-%02d\n", array[i]->name, array[i]->Birth_date.year, array[i]->Birth_date.month, array[i]->Birth_date.day);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your patience and will to help me. I'm using this and my code doesn't show any of the warning i mentioned before. Thank you!